# Ubuntu Node js With Socket io Not allowing client to connect

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I'm trying to get the socket.io working in Ubuntu using Nodejs. 
Tried to disable the firewall, open ports 3000,4000.

I'm using PM2.

Deployed In **DigitalOcean**

Now in my Angular client App I get this error

Also I have core errors setup in my node js

```
  client:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'mydomain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N4_SuJm' 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Although I did publish the same code in AWS ElasticBeanstalk and it worked just fine so nothing wrong with the code**

---

### UPDATE

**I managed to solve the issue**

Comment: Hey I think this is an issue with the cors configuration on your server. I would suggest going through this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-enable-cors-on-node-js-production-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx-proxy

as it seems to be a cors issue  but I cannot be sure till there are more error logs/info.

Comment: Yes looks like a cors issue.

Comment: thanks for the replay , i tried that and didnt work , I can do a get / post / delete ... requests just cant connect to my socket io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

**I managed to solve the issue**

> **For future reference**
>
> the problem was that the socketio client removes the path from the url
>   that is given when connecting exampledomin.com/api is the correct path
>   for socketio in node js but the socket io client removes the /api and
>   points it to /socketio so i added a Location in the nginx config to
>   point to the server hope this will help someone down the road